# How to access angular components property in cypress

Tags: angular, cypress

I have a captcha component in angular and I have to access this components variable X in my test script.

captcha component.ts:

```
export class CaptchaComponent{
    public x:number; // it is a random value in every call
};
```

my test.cy.ts:

```
 it('login', () => {
    cy.get('#submit-button').click();
    let amountX = ### how to access here
    cy.get('.slider').trigger('mousedown', { button: 0, force: true}).trigger('mousemove', amountX, 100, { force: true}).trigger('mouseup');
};
```

I tried to mock but I think I shouldn't mock it because need actual value.

Edit: can't use window.ng I think because of test run in production mode

Comment: Is this an E2E test or a component test?

Comment: @DJSDev E2E test and can't use window.ng because test run in production mode

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, they give an example of how to access the component instance directly [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/angular/examples#Accessing-the-Component-Instance)

In the following example. I used this method to access a "currentCard" property

```
    it('should go to the second card', () => {
    cy.mount(MyComponent, {
        declarations: [MyComponent],
        imports: [CommonModule],
        componentProperties: {
            cardsLenght: 3,             
        },
    }).then((wrapper) => {
        cy.get('[data-cy="next-btn"]').click();
        cy.wrap(wrapper.component).its('currentCard').should('eq', 2)
    });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work if you aim to check a property later in the it block.